# A UICollectionView bug?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` while doing the following:

- Return a string array in `collectionView:indexPathForIndexTitle:atIndex:`
- Set `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` on `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

(Notice that changing the background color of the cell is just for demonstrating the issue. The important thing is to show index titles on the right.)

The result (as following displayed) is that the content view takes the entire collection view width and it doesn't being affected (as it should) by the appearance of the index titles.

[image]

With `UITableViewController` I am doing similar steps:

- Return a string array in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`
- Set `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` on `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Here, in contrast to the collection view behavior, the content view is "shrinking" as expected as following appear:

[image]

Can anyone tell if this is a bug or the expected behavior?

Comment: A collection view is totally different from a table view. A collection view has no automatic layout behavior at all. How collection view cells are positioned and sized is up to _you_, by way of the collection view layout object. _You_ are the one who is setting the collection view cell size. You have concealed the code where you are doing that, but I assure you that you are doing it. If you want the cell to be smaller, _you_ need to make it smaller. Do not expect anything to be done magically for you.

Comment: @matt If I manually set the cell size depending on the appearance of index titles, how can I tell the width of the index title column?

Comment: That isn't what you asked. You asked if this was a bug. It isn't.

Comment: Even if not a bug, it seems like API is missing to get the width of the index titles column. This width seems to be different on iPhone vs iPad.

Comment: Yep, maybe. _But that is not what you asked_.

Comment: Got it. Will post a new question, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear and obvious, but i will try to answer.

First: try to set UITableView's (actually UIScrollView's) property 'showVerticalScrollIndicator' to false (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619405-showsverticalscrollindicator?language=objc)

Second: try to play with TableView 'contentInset', 'separator inset'  properties. Perfectly, you should set 'separatorStyle' to 'none' and use your custom separator-cells, or conditionally set bottom line inside cells (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614909-separatorstyle)

Third: check out how to customize Header of Table or Header/Footer of Collection:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview

One more important thing: you may always Examine a View Hierarchy. Check out this link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question... I am switching from UITableView to UICollectionView. My cell content sometimes takes the entire width and therefore "touches" the index titles (when they appear). My question is actually how to prevent that. With UITableView there is no issue since the table view automatically resizes the cells when index titles appear. In collection view there is no automatic resize.

Comment: My apologies for late reply. Did you solve the problem?

I recommend you to inspect view hierarchy as i mentioned in answer.

I suppose two solutions:
1. implement FlowLayout's size for cell (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview)
2. Do not use contentView, instead inside a cell create container view with right offset. (layout anchors top0 left 0, bottom 0 right -20). Lay out any view inside this container.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, though I don't really like it. I am using auto-layout constraints and update them dynamically as the index titles appear or disappear. The problem with this solution is that I need to assume the width of the index titles (e.g. 20) while it varies across device types and might even change in future iOS versions.